# Out of memory when unmarshaling the xml in camel dsl

Tags: apache-camel, unmarshalling

I m facing OOM issue in below code

```
from("file://" + getDumpDirLocation() + "?maxMessagesPerPoll=1&bufferSize=8192")
                .unmarshal().string("UTF-8")
```

The xml file which gets dumped at the directory location is huge (sometimes 1G).

I also tried by adding a custom processor - but no success,

```
from("file://" + getDumpDirLocation() + "?maxMessagesPerPoll=1&bufferSize=8192")
.process(this.getRemoveInvalidXmlCharacterProcessor())
```

Is there any way to avoid this out of memory exception?

So basically exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class) in the processor throws OOM as the object structure is huge considering the size of dumped XML file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its really not a good idea to read in 1GB of file into memory. Instead read the file in "chunks" using streaming.

And if you want to process big XML files then read some of these articles, you can find here: http://camel.apache.org/articles about splitting big xml files. Just search on that page for xml, and you can find the links.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Java memory exception. Nothing to do with camel I reckon. Separating out to a custom processor won't make any difference.

You have to *increase runtime memory for JVM*.
If you are using Eclipse, set -Xmx2048M as VM argument under Run configurations for the particular application that you intend to run.

If in any other environment, you can do a simple search to find out how to increase java heapsize and that should solve the problem.

Comment: say -Xmx2048M is used, then what happens if the size of the file to be processed is more than 2 gb.